# How to convert simple array into two-dimensional array(matrix) in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran

I had to read data from a file and store all data in a one dimensional array.
However, Some data I have to store in a matrix (2 dimensional array) How Can I do this?

For example if my data is `1x7` array `[1,2,3,1,5,2,8]` and the first to 6th belong to a matrix `2x3` how can I store in a new array variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that your 7-element array is called `array7`, then the following expression should return a `2x3` array containing the first 6 elements of `array7`

```
reshape(array7(1:6),[2,3])
```

If that puts the elements into the new array in the wrong order, try

```
reshape(array7(1:6),[2,3],order=[2,1])
```

Note that I've used a named optional argument in the second version, there is another optional argument (`pad`) which would be, by default, the 3rd argument to `reshape`.

Comment: hi. I wrote a piece of code @High Performance Mark [link=codeinPasteBin](http://pastebin.com/gg2vskgL) inspired of what you said. However, I got an error on reshape instructions.
    reshape(inArray(1:6),[2,ntens])
    1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
reshapeArray.f90:29.26:

        write(*,*) inArray(i,1:2)
                          1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (2/1)

Comment: You have to do some of your work yourself. If you read the documentation you will find that `reshape` is an intrinsic function which returns an array; you have to use it rather like this: `result = reshape(...)`. `reshape` is not a Fortran statement.